# storing username to mysql [PYTHON]

Tags: python, mysql

Hey guys it's been a while since I picked back up in python, but i'm finishing some old projects, and i'm kinda stuck.  So i'm trying to get the username data to submit to a mysqldb. Here is my code, and errors thanks. Another issue; for the MysqlVersion error, I'm not sure what the deal is? It looks correct to me, but then again it's late at night.

Note: I'm new to mysql, and I'm aware my code is really sloppy. ( I'm insecure about that!I will clean it up later)

IDE: Pycharm

Error: http://pastebin.com/pvwPCSXB

Code: http://pastebin.com/LYgSbKbM

Comment: Please add the code and traceback to your question, don't link them.

Comment: Pictures of code and error messages are not helpful - please add text.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this :

```
add_user = ("INSERT INTO user_pwd "
            "(name)")
```

With this :

```
add_user = ("INSERT INTO `user_pwd`(`COLUMN_NAME`) VALUES ("+name+")")
```

Just replace `COLUMN_NAME` with the name of the column where the name value should be placed.

Comment: I'm getting this now

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Zachary/PycharmProjects/NetworkChating/NetWork Chat/registeration/auser.py", line 16, in <module>
    add_user = ("INSERT INTO `user_pwd`(`NAME`) VALUES ("+name+")")
NameError: name 'name' is not defined

I'm not sure how ("+name+) is being done? I've never seen something like this.